# How to get Data Analysis button on Data Tab of online version of MS Excel?

Tags: excel

How to get Data Analysis button on Data Tab of online version of MS Excel from add ins?
I want to create **histogram** of frequency usin bins

Comment: You can't as far as I know.

Comment: Yes! you are partialy right  we can get data analysis tool which gave frequency count and bin table ,ya but can't built histogram